# Pass class constructor as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I'm trying to create component based entities with mixins. To define entities I have a template class taking all components as template parameter:

```
template<typename Mixin>
struct EntityFactoy : Mixin, Entity
{
    void preUpdate(float dt)
    {Mixin::mixinPreUpdate(dt);}
    void update(float dt)
    {Mixin::mixinUpdate(dt);}
    void lateUpdate(float dt)
    {Mixin::mixinLateUpdate(dt);}
};
```

To define a new entity I just create a typedef:

```
using MyEntity = EntityFactory<Component1<Component2<ComponentN<>>>>;
```

Now I'd like to pass a constructor to this template, so the entity can initialize it's components.

```
x = Entity1(3, 2.2f, "string");
y = Entity2("string", &x);
```

I tried some things like passing a variadic template or even switched to an ugly macro, but neither of them worked like I wanted. Note that the mixins all have default constructors.

Edit:

I tried it with variadic templates, but I still don't know how to get the implementation in there:

```
template<typename Mixin, typename CtrArgs>
struct EntityFactory : Mixin, Entity
{
    EntityFactory(CtrArgs&&... args)
    {
        //Define this via a template parameter
    }
    void preUpdate(float dt)
    {Mixin::mixinPreUpdate(dt);}
    void update(float dt)
    {Mixin::mixinUpdate(dt);}
    void lateUpdate(float dt)
    {Mixin::mixinLateUpdate(dt);}
};
```

Or somehow pass a function as template:

```
template<typename Mixin, typename Ctor>
struct EntityFactory : Mixin, Entity
{
    EntityFactory() = Ctor;
    void preUpdate(float dt)
    {Mixin::mixinPreUpdate(dt);}
    void update(float dt)
    {Mixin::mixinUpdate(dt);}
    void lateUpdate(float dt)
    {Mixin::mixinLateUpdate(dt);}
 };
```

Is a macro the only way of doing this?

Comment: Why not show us the "some things" with actual code examples, and tell us exactly what didn't work?

Comment: Surely `Entity(std::forward<CtrArgs>(args)...)` will create an  `Entity` from the parameters passed to the factory. But the factory doesn't seem to store or return the object created, so it is a bit unclear what you are looking for.

Comment: Your post is confusing. What are `x` and `y`? Are these datamembers of the components? Or just custom `EntityFactory` instantiations aliased as `Entity1` and `Entity2`? Please provide your intent with that constructor using actual provided classes.